# How do I add a new string to a .po or .pot file?

Tags: themes, buddypress

I have a .pot file that came with my Wordpress theme. Now I want to add strings to it, that weren't there in the original theme. How do I do that?
Do I have to update the .pot file? but 1) How do I do that, and 2) How do I make sure that the strings that were translated won't get erased?
(I'm currently using [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) and I can't see a feature to add a string.)

Comment: I think this question is not WordPress-specific enough to stay on this site, so maybe you should re-post it on Stack Overflow, or maybe Super User (since you also mention a program).

Comment: @Jan I edited the question so that it's more Wordpress oriented and not program specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/
Give it a chance i suggest :)

Comment: This plugin link is dead. Anybody got any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shell script to generate pot files automatically. Modify the copyright, etc to fit your needs:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Author: Denis de Bernardy <http://www.mesoconcepts.com>
# Version: 0.1
# GPL licensed
#
# Created by Ryan Boren
# Later code and patches from
# Kimmo Suominen (more) and Nikolay Bachiyski (less)
# Denis de Bernardy

cwd=`pwd`

if [ -n "$1" ];
then
    cd "$1" || exit 1
    slug=`basename $1`
    dir=$cwd/$slug
else
    dir=$cwd
    slug=`basename $cwd`
fi

pot_file=$slug.pot

cp /dev/null "$dir/$pot_file"

find . -name '*.php' -print \
| sed -e 's,^\./,,' \
| sort \
| xargs xgettext \
    --keyword=__ \
    --keyword=_e \
    --keyword=_c \
    --keyword=__ngettext:1,2 \
    --keyword=_n:1,2 \
    --default-domain=$slug \
    --language=php \
    --output="$dir/$pot_file" \
    --join-existing \
    --from-code utf-8 \
    --copyright-holder='Mesoconcepts <http://www.mesoconcepts.com>' \
    --msgid-bugs-address=https://tickets.semiologic.com

# sub only the YEAR in the copyright message (the 2nd line)
sed -i '' -e '2s/YEAR/'`date +%Y`'/' "$pot_file"

# and the cherry of the pie - extract version using magic - versoextracanus!~

if [ -f $dir/style.css ];
then
    name=`fgrep -i 'Theme Name:' $dir/style.css`
    version=`fgrep -i 'Version:' $dir/style.css`
elif [ -f $dir/$slug.php ];
then
    #statements
    name=`fgrep -i 'Plugin Name:' $dir/$slug.php`
    version=`fgrep -i 'Version:' $dir/$slug.php`
else
    name=$slug
    version=
fi

name=${name##*:}
name=${name##[[:space:]]}
version=${version##*:}
version=${version##[[:space:]]}
version=${version%%[[:space:]]*}

if [ "$name" != '' ];
then
    sed -i '' -e "1s/^# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE/# $name pot file/" "$pot_file"
    sed -i '' -e "s/\(^#.*\)PACKAGE\(.*\)/\1$name\2/g" "$pot_file"
fi

if [ "$version" != '' ];
then
    sed -i '' -e "s/\(Project-Id-Version: \)PACKAGE VERSION/\1$version/" "$pot_file"
fi

cd "$cwd"
```

Usage, assuming a *nix box (Mac or Linux):

- place the above in ~/bin/gen_pot.sh and make it executable
- make sure that ~/bin is in your $PATH
- in wp-content/themes, run gen_pot.sh yourtheme
- or from within in your theme's dir, run gen_pot.sh
- it'll output the pot file automatically...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good idea. With [iCanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/tools/create_po_from_php), you can create a `.po` file automatically.

> This generator will scan PHP file(s) and create .po files, that are used for localization. It will extract all strings wrapped in `__("txt", "domain")` and `_e("txt", "domain")` calls.
>
> Strings can be enclosed in either double quotes (") or single quotes(') and with any character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [WP-CLI installed](https://wp-cli.org/) (command-line interface for WordPress), this can be achieved with the following command:

`wp i18n make-pot --merge source_dir target.pot`

Comment: Welcome to WPSE and thanks for taking the time to answer. That said, I am not sure this answers the questions. Could you please add a little more of context or explaing how this answer would be an [appropriated answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?